# Passing a php generated table to another php via ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a php shopping cart and I am trying to post the data in the cart to another php file to post the data to a new database.

I pushed the table data to an array and used JSON.stringify and passed that to php file then decoded.

When I try `$data[2]['prodName']` I get the value of the first row's prodName.

```
<?php
  
    $data = stripcslashes($_POST['tabledata']);
    $data = json_decode($data, true);

  echo $data[2]['prodName'];
      
?>
```

When I try to run this in a for loop and use $data[$x]['prodID'] it fails

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "prodName" in F:\DreamCPU
> backup\PHPConnect\checkout.php on line 8

```
<?php
  
$data = stripcslashes($_POST['tabledata']);
$data = json_decode($data, true);

for($x=0; $x < count($data); $x++)
{
   echo $data[$x]['prodName'];
}
?>
```

I would like to iterate through this array and post the data to the other database

This is what the table looks like

[image]

This is what I get when I run `print_r($data);`:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [prodID] => 2 [prodName] => Little Mermaid Doll 2023 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid Doll 2023 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [prodID] => 3 [prodName] => Little Mermaid TShirt 1989 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid TShirt 1989 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [prodID] => 4 [prodName] => Little Mermaid TShirt 2023 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid TShirt 2023 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) 
  [3] => Array ( ) 
)
```

Comment: What you posted doesn't look like a `var_dump()`.

Comment: What is the output shown from print_r($data);  if you add it after the json_decode line?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [prodID] => 2 [prodName] => Little Mermaid Doll 2023 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid Doll 2023 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) [1] => Array ( [prodID] => 3 [prodName] => Little Mermaid TShirt 1989 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid TShirt 1989 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) [2] => Array ( [prodID] => 4 [prodName] => Little Mermaid TShirt 2023 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid TShirt 2023 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) [3] => Array ( ) )

Comment: This is what I get when I do print_r()

Comment: Is is the last entry, the empty array (`[3] => Array ( ) `) which is causing the error (because it does not contain a "prodName" property in it). Presumably your client-side code submitted an empty row, for some reason. You should probably debug that code and find out why.

Comment: I made a change on my code I searched tr by class name just in case it was pulling data from the if else statement I had in my code. This is the current print_r                                                                              `Array ( [0] => Array ( [prodID] => 2 [prodName] => Little Mermaid Doll 2023 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid Doll 2023 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) [1] => Array ( [prodID] => 3 [prodName] => Little Mermaid TShirt 1989 [prodDesc] => Little Mermaid TShirt 1989 [prodQuantity] => 1 [prodPrice] => 15.00 [prodSub] => 15.00 ) )`

Comment: Tested with loop and did not get an error :) now testing to see if I can post all of the data into a database Fingers Crossed

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It was a tr that was getting passed in the array which I did not need.Using tr.ProdClass to call the tr I needed worked and fixed the issue

Comment: That's great. If you think it would help others please add your fixed code as an Answer below. Then you can get votes for it, and the question shows as solved and is higher in searches. Or you could just delete the question.

Comment: I'll add the code in the morning. I have the other modules to add now that this is working